# Haskell Define Data Type

Tags: haskell

I trying to create a type class `Place` which has `String Coord [Int]` , and a `testData` to store all the element into a list

```
data Place =  Place String Coord [Int]
             deriving (Ord,Eq,Show,Read)

data Coord = Cord Double Double
             deriving (Ord ,Eq ,Show ,Read)


testData :: [Place]
testData = [  "London"       Cord(51.5  ,-0.1)   0, 0, 5, 8, 8, 0, 0 
              "Cardiff"      Cord(51.5  ,-3.2)   12, 8, 15, 0, 0, 0, 2
              "Norwich"      Cord(52.6  , 1.3)   0, 6, 5, 0, 0, 0, 3 
              "Birmingham"   Cord(52.5  ,-1.9)   0, 2, 10, 7, 8, 2, 2
              "Liverpool"    Cord(53.4  ,-3.0)   8, 16, 20, 3, 4, 9, 2
              "Hull"         Cord(53.8  ,-0.3)   0, 6, 5, 0, 0, 0, 4
              "Newcastle"    Cord(55.0  ,-1.6)   0, 0, 8, 3, 6, 7, 5
              "Belfast"      Cord(54.6  ,-5.9)   10, 18, 14, 0, 6, 5, 2
              "Glasgow"      Cord(55.9  ,-4.3)   7, 5, 3, 0, 6, 5, 0
              "Plymouth"     Cord(50.4  ,-4.1)   4, 9, 0, 0, 0, 6, 5
              "Aberdeen"     Cord(57.1  ,-2.1)   0, 0, 6, 5, 8, 2, 0
              "Stornoway"    Cord(58.2  ,-6.4)   15, 6, 15, 0, 0, 4, 2
              "Lerwick"      Cord(60.2  ,-1.1)   8, 10, 5, 5, 0, 0, 3
              "St Helier"    Cord(49.2  ,-2.1)     0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 10, 0 ]
```

But it keep giving me this error

```
UP917725.hs:20:15: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘(Double -> Double -> Coord)
                                    -> (Double, Double) -> Integer -> Place’
                  with actual type ‘[Char]’
    • The function ‘"London"’ is applied to three arguments,
      but its type ‘[Char]’ has none
      In the expression: "London" Cord (51.5, - 0.1) 0
      In the expression: ["London" Cord (51.5, - 0.1) 0, 0, 5, 8, ....]
   |
20 | testData = [  "London"       Cord(51.5  ,-0.1)   0, 0, 5, 8, 8, 0, 0     |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

It keep saying that the actual type is `Char`, I also tried putting  parenthesis with the int list aswell , So I probably think the error is somewhere around the definition of the datatype

Comment: Welcome to SO! What is going on with all these posts about the exact same exercise of this one haskell course at portsmouth uni?

Comment: `Cord(x,y)` should be `(Cord x y)` in your definition of `testData`. The data constructor has kind `Double -> Double -> Coord`, not `(Double, Double) -> Coord`.

Answer (score 4):

Your datatype definition is perfectly fine, you are just missing the `Place` data constructor in your list. Also function application has a different syntax in `Haskell`. Instead of `Cord(53.8, -0.3)` you have to use `Cord 53.8 (-0.3)`.

For example:

```
testData :: [Place]
testData = [ Place "London" (Cord 51.5 (-0.1)) [0, 0, 5, 8, 8, 0, 0]
           , Place "Cardiff" (Cord 51.5 (-3.2)) [12, 8, 15, 0, 0, 0, 2]
           -- etc.
           ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's reduce this to the minimal list that has the same problem:

```
testData = [  "London"       Cord(51.5  ,-0.1)   0, 0, 5, 8, 8, 0, 0 
              "Cardiff"      Cord(51.5  ,-3.2)   12, 8, 15, 0, 0, 0, 2 ]
```

First note that though Haskell does have indentation sensitivity, the line break does not mean anything here. This is actually parsed as

```
testData = [  ("London"       Cord(51.5  ,-0.1)   0), 0, 5, 8, 8, 0, (0 
               "Cardiff"      Cord(51.5  ,-3.2)   12), 8, 15, 0, 0, 0, 2 ]
```

or

```
testData = [ "London" Cord (51.5,-0.1) 0
           , 0
           ‥‥
           , 0
           , 0 "Cardiff" Cord (51.5,-3.2) 12
           , 8
           ‥‥ 
           , 2 
           ]
```

i.e. the separators of list elements are completely different from what you intended. To get that each *city* is an entry, put the commas between them and and ensure that any finer-lever commas are encapsulated in parens – in doubt, by putting each list entry entirely in a paren:

```
testData = [ ("London"       Cord(51.5  ,-0.1)   0, 0, 5, 8, 8, 0, 0)
           , ("Cardiff"      Cord(51.5  ,-3.2)   12, 8, 15, 0, 0, 0, 2) ]
```

Now, by simply having commas in parens you make these list entries *tuples*. That's not what you want, but let's go for it for now...

The first tuple entry would be

```
   "London" Cord(51.5  ,-0.1) 0
```

Again, whitespace doesn't really affect parsing; this is the same as

```
   "London" (Cord) (51.5,-0.1) (0)
```

which would mean, you apply the function `"London"` to the arguments `Coord`, then `(51.5,-0.1)`, then `0`. How can `"London"` possibly be a function?

No, what you want is have `"London"` as the *first data field* of a `Place` value. `Place` is a tuple-ish type, but it's not literally a tuple: to generate a `Place` value out of the desired data-field values, you need to use its *constructor*, which also happens to be called `Place`. (It's common in Haskell to give constructors the same name as the type they construct, but it could just as well be called different.) So that would be

```
     Place "London" Cord(51.5  ,-0.1) 0
```

Still not right: `Cord` and `(51.5,-0.1)` are separate here regardless of whether you have whitespace between them, so this would be parsed

```
     Place ("London") (Cord) (51.5  ,-0.1) (0)
```

Instead you want

```
     Place "London" (Cord (51.5  ,-0.1)) 0
```

We're almost done. Only, that `0` wasn't actually supposed to be provided on its own: what you want there is a *list* of ints, of which `0` was only the head.

Well, solution is to put all those list-entry numbers in brackets, specifically list-brackets:

```
     Place "London" (Cord (51.5  ,-0.1)) [0, 0, 5, 8, 8, 0, 0]
```

Then, one last thing: `Coord` is also a constructor, taking floating-point numbers. But you give it *a single tuple* of such numbers. So instead of `Cord (51.5,-0.1)`, you want `Cord 51.5 (-0.1)`.

Comment: You should update to call `Cord` correctly; the OP's usage doesn't match its defined type.